# Python: Selenium "no such element" XPath or ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to log into Tessco.com
I have learned this site uses JavaScript, which is why I was unable to locate a form using RoboBrowser.

I am now using Selenium. I have used two methods to enter information into a field. One, using the `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`as well as `driver.find_element_by_id()`

Both attempts yield an error. 
The code is as follows:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\James\Documents\Python Scripts\jupyterNoteBooks\ScrapingData\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.tessco.com/login")

userName = "FirstName.SurName321123@gmail.com"
password = "PasswordForThis123"

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="userID"]""")
elem = send_keys(userName)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="password"]""")
elem = send_keys(password)

driver.close()
```

The error is:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="userID"]"}
```

When I call the element by using ID as such:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("userID")
elem = send_keys(userName)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
elem = send_keys(password)
```

I get:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="userID"]"}
```

I was under the impression I inspected the element and used the appropriate names.

Any hints or ideas what I am not doing correctly?

---

---

---

---

---

Solution provided below in the comments section.
Code modified to:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
#Webdriver wait functions being introduced to add a delay.
#I was running into problems, with the ID not being found
#add wait for the element to be clickable before trying send keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\James\Documents\Python Scripts\jupyterNoteBooks\ScrapingData\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.tessco.com/login")

userName = "FirstName.SurName321123@gmail.com"
password = "PasswordForThis123"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userID"))) 
elem.send_keys(userName)

elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))) 
elem.send_keys(password)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a WebDriverWait and wait for the element to be clickable before trying send keys?

Comment: It sounds like the `userID` element is not present when the page first loads, but is dynamically created a short time later.  You need to tell selenium to wait until that element is present.

Comment: @JeffC I love this site and its amazing community. That worked like a charm, I guess the element wasn't loaded yet. Thank you. I'll modify my post to include the solution.

Comment: @JamesHayek I would suggest please provide your tried solution in the answer section instead of posting it in the question section. Thanks

Comment: Great. I've added my comment as an answer and expanded on it some.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I did this intentionally so, Jeff, the solution provider can get the credit for the answer. That, and also so the future reader can obtain a solution without scrolling too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the element is not visible at first and that causes the failure. Wait until the element is visible/clickable and then use send keys.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userID"))).send_keys(userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the element search happens before its loaded. My suggestion would try putting some wait and it should work.